# Was anything past volume 7 ever released in English?

Tags: satisfaction-guaranteed

I'm referring to the manga [Satisfaction Guaranteed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satisfaction_Guaranteed_%28manga%29) by Ryo Saenagi. I came across this manga quite a few years ago, and really loved it!  I bought the first 7 volumes in English, which are distributed by Tokyopop. When I was finished reading them I tried to find volume 8 on Amazon, but didn't have any luck.  I searched and found that, in Japanese, [nine volumes](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/manga.php?id=5299&page=28) were released to complete the series.  But I couldn't find them in English anywhere.

I come back to this problem every couple of years and do a search in hope that something has changed, but I still can never find volumes 8 or 9.  Does anyone have any idea what happened to this manga?  If it really was never released in English beyond volume 7, as seems to be the case, then it seems the best I could hope for is to buy the volumes in Japanese and find a translation somewhere on the internet. If anyone knows where I can find such a thing, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: When Tokyopop, the English publisher closed it's doors, a lots of series were left handing. While some were picked up, others were not. *Satisfaction Guaranteed* is definitely one of them.

Comment: @Krazer But volume 7 was released May 6, 2008, and according to wikipedia Tokyopop announced it was closing on April 15, 2011. It seems weird to me that the other books weren't published in those 3 years? (Thanks for the tag, by the way :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@Krazer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/63/krazer) [mentioned above](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3306/satisfaction-guaranteed-was-anything-past-volume-7-ever-released-in-english#comment2533_3306), *Satisfaction Guaranteed* was one of the projects that [Tokyopop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokyopop) was publishing. However, in 2011, the company was shut down, and the publishing of the project went along with it.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satisfaction_Guaranteed_(manga)#Manga) cites volume 7 as being the last (English) release as of July 31, 2010. According to AnimeNewsNetwork, there is a [theoretical volume 8](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/releases.php?id=11625) in English; however, that information was posted prior to the suggested release date of the volume, and it appears to have never come to fruition.

So it does seem that volume 7 is the last official English version. You'll probably have better luck looking for a Chinese or Japanese version (even English fan translations past volume 3 appear to be scarce*).

<sub>* Unfortunately, we [cannot link](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/389/274) to scanlations or online readers for legal reasons.</sub>